# How can I install mini aluminium heatsink to wireless card?

Tags: wireless, heatsink

I am thinking about increasing txpower of the my wireless card. But I am worrying about the heat can damage my wireless card. My solution is installing aliminium heatsinks on the wireless card.
My wireless adaptor is TP Link WN722N V1.X. And I don't know that if my card support heatsinks.

Example for mini aluminium heatsink : https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpIXD.jpg

**Question:** I don't know how can I install these mini aliminium heatsinks because my circuit card does not have holes for heatsink installation.

How and where can I create holes for heatsink installation at the following wireless card?

Or is there any way to install those mini aliminum heatsinks without creating holes on wireless card?

[image]

Comment: What makes you think that you can increase the output power of your WiFi card, and if this is in fact possible, what makes you think that a heatsink would be necessary?

Comment: I don't know what is the logic behind this but I have seen too many people that damaged their wireless cards by manipulating txpower.A lot of operating systems do not allow manipulation of txpower with software but some operating systems do.

Comment: What do you mean "don't know if it supports heatsinks"? I'm not sure it's possible for something to just "not support" heatsinks!

Comment: you can buy "heat sink glue" or "heat sink cement" instead of grease. it's not quite as conductive, but it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look again at those heatsinks you linked you'll see that they have an adhesive pad on the bottom for precisely this purpose.

I've used those without any issues in light duty applications. If you want it to be more secure, you can add a metal clip of some kind that grabs the edges of the pcb, and passes between the fins of the heatsink. That will be extremely secure and also provide some contact pressure.